# Coldfusion / Railo paths question for live server

Tags: iis, coldfusion, railo

My website files are located with the folder structure as such:

```
* Webroot
   ** mydomain   
   ** sharedimages
```

In IIS, my website is setup with www.mydomain.com pointing to Webroot->mydomain as it's home directory.

In my site, I need to somehow display images located in the 'sharedimages' folder. 
Obviously though, I can't go www.mydomain.com/sharedimages/image1.jpg.
I also can't use mappings as it's a webpath.

Is there anyway around this??

The only way I know is to make the home folder for www.mydomain.com the 'Webroot' folder, but then my website is always displaying www.mydomain.com/mydomain/index.cfm which I don't want.

I would like the url to read www.mydomain.com and still keep that folder structure the same. 
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a virtual directory in IIS for the sharedimages folder.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138